# Splitting Zip Files Based on Number of Files, Not Size

Tags: applescript, archive, zip

I'm looking to setup an automater script on my Mac.

On a daily basis I'm compressing thousands of files into groups of 75 files by manually selecting the 75 and compressing them.

Is there a way to setup an automater script to where I can highlight 1000 images and run a script that would take 75 files at a time and zip them together without me having to manually select the 75 files?

Comment: 1000 is not equally divisible by 75, so what do you want to do with the last 25 files? Or if you select less then 75 files, what do you want to do?

Comment: @user3439894 ZIP them I guess?

Comment: @JBis, I'm not going to assume either way because 75 seems to be the magic number here.

Comment: 75 is not a hard and fast number. If there are 25 files left, they would be zipped into there own file as well. :) And the same would go for if you were to select less than 75, it would zip them up. The goal is to have all files zipped into downloadable files by non-techsavvy users who do not know about split zip files.

Comment: The total number of files would be highlighted or you could point the script to the location where all the files are.